# windowed exe using pyinstaller with -w option not work

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This is my first post, thanks for viewing in advance.
I wanted to convert test.py to test.exe using pyinstaller. Everything worked fine until I tried to use -w option to get rid of the console window. It says-

```
'Failed to execute script test'
```

Below is the code -

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I guess when using '-w' option for script with external applications like browser it will pop up with this error?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

your script is fine, it's the way you are using pyinstaller. to get rid of the console window you need pyinstaller added to your system path and then type this in a regular command prompt:

```
pyinstaller script.py --windowed
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Pyinstaller is already in my sys path. I have no probelm using it with other options like -F -i. But when I used -w option for scripts that contain external applications it won't work properly.

Comment: In Windows, use the cmd.exe tool to navigate to the folder that contains script.exe and then execute the script.exe from cmd.exe.  You should get the traceback in the cmd window.